# "on most of the accounts"

Tags: phrases

> On most of the accounts, life of a farmer is very hard.

Is the use of the phrase 'on most of the accounts' right here? If not, what will be the best substitution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're probably looking for:

> By most accounts, the life of a farmer is very hard.

This would mean that according to most people, a farmer's life is very hard.

Otherwise I'm not sure what `on most of the accounts` would mean in this context.